# Open/Edit Triggers Only Work for Creator in New Google Sheets

Tags: menu, triggers, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It seems that if I create an open or edit trigger in the new Google Sheets, it only runs it for the user who created the trigger. I do NOT experience this issue in the old Google sheets. Here are the steps I am following:

1. Create a Google Spreadsheet (the new version).
2. Create a new script function, such as one that creates a custom menu.
3. Manually create a trigger so that this function is executed when the spreadsheet is opened. (I think the issue still occurs with the functions that have auto-triggers, like `onOpen()` and `onEdit()`.
4. Now open the spreadsheet as the same user. Notice that the custom menu will show up properly.
5. Open the spreadsheet as a different user who has edit access to the spreadsheet. In the old Google Sheets, this new user would see the custom menu. However, the function does not seem to even attempt execution in the new Google Sheets, even if I use the *exact* same code.

Here is some example code, just to confirm I'm not doing anything wrong on the scripting side:

```
function createMenu() {
  var menuItems = [
    {name: "Test Menu Item", functionName: "test"}
  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu("Test Menu", menuItems);
}

function test(){

}
```

**NOTE:** I've tried this with other pieces of code, too, so I'm almost positive it's not an issue with syntax or anything like that. When I run it MANUALLY as the second user, it creates the menu just fine. The issue is that the Open trigger isn't working properly in the new sheets.

I've reproduced this in two different Google Account domains (or whatever those organization things are called). I've also reproduced it on multiple spreadsheets. Let me know if you need any more details.

**EDIT**: Google confirmed that it is an issue with changing the client-side UI from an open/edit trigger. Please star the issue if you would like it to get fixed or would like to receive updates on it: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4021&thanks=4021&ts=1400503046

Comment: Instead of adding that final EDIT to your question, post the same information as an answer. You are allowed (encouraged, even) to answer your own... it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google confirmed that it is an issue with changing the client-side UI from an open/edit trigger. Please star the issue if you would like it to get fixed or would like to receive updates on it: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4021&thanks=4021&ts=1400503046